# open a mailbox to which I have full access

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I can open my mailbox in exchange online with EWS and Powershell

```
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService  
$service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $mail, $password
$service.URL = New-Object Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")  
$view = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView($numOfEmailsToRead, $index)
$folderview = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(10)
$folderview.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$folderview.PropertySet.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName)
$folderview.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
$folderfindResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $folderview)
$SearchFilterContainsSubString = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, $Paramerter)
$SearchFilterNot = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+Not($SearchFilterContainsSubString)
foreach ($InboxFolder in $folderfindResults) {

  $findResultsItems = $InboxFolder.findItems($SearchFilterNot,$view)}
```

How do I change the code to open a mailbox to which I have full access?

Comment: Without having tried this approach, I'd say the key to success is likely to be in the second line of code. Have you tried changing anything? Have you read any of the code or is it something you found online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you need to use the Mailbox overload for Folder id so change

```
        $folderfindResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $folderview)
    $SearchFilterContainsSubString = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, $Paramerter)
    $SearchFilterNot = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+Not($SearchFilterContainsSubString)
    foreach ($InboxFolder in $folderfindResults) {

    $findResultsItems = $InboxFolder.findItems($SearchFilterNot,$view)}
```

To

```
    $MailboxToAccess = "blah@blah.com"   
    $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxToAccess)     
    $folderfindResults = $service.FindFolders($folderid, $folderview)
    $SearchFilterContainsSubString = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, $Paramerter)
    $SearchFilterNot = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+Not($SearchFilterContainsSubString)
    foreach ($InboxFolder in $folderfindResults) {

    $findResultsItems = $InboxFolder.findItems($SearchFilterNot,$view)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of connecting to a different mailbox

```
$MailboxName = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Mailbox("support@domain.com") #specifies which mailbox EWS should connect to

$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName) 

$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
```

For more detailed info please read this blog: https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2016/10/ews-basics-accessing-and-using-shared.html

Comment: Thanks moszti. Unfortunately, I do not know the subfolder.
So as above from the code, need an array with all subolders under the inbox folder.

Comment: my example simple showed you how you can use the Mailbox overload of the folderId for opening mailboxes others than yours. I've shown you the way and you could just easily import it into your code- 2 lines needed to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support.
I was able to do it with the line

```
$service.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress,$Mailbox);
```

Resolve.

I was getting a 401 error. The error was because I had overwritten the credentials. Now everything works.

In Exchange the executing user needs the role
"ApplicationImpersonation"